# Postgresql: How to get value in JSON where key LIKE?

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-like

I have a column in my table containing a JSON `statuses_json`:

```
{
    "demoStatus" : "true",
    "productionStatus": "false"
}
```

I would like to retrieve a value where the key is LIKE some string.
For example, if I pass in "demo", I want to retrieve the value for the key `demoStatus`.

Right now I am able to retrieve values when passing the exact key:

```
`statuses_json->>'productionStatus' = 'false' `;
```

Comment: jsonb_path_query?  I don't have a new enough version of postgresql to test it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the keys and run a query on it:

```
select *
from json_object_keys('{
    "demoStatus" : "true",
    "productionStatus": "false"
}') k where k like '%demo%';
```

I don't have a new enough version of postgresql but `jsonb_path_query` looks interesting, too.  Then used `statuses_json->>(...)` to extract the corresponding value(s).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select statuses_json from your_table
where statuses_json->>(
    select prop
    from json_object_keys(statuses_json) as prop
    where prop like 'demo%'
) = 'false';
```

Comment: Your inner query will produce a collection, so you cannot use an `=` operator there